# jQuery colorbox - close iframe with onclick, can I time this event

Tags: jquery, colorbox

My iframe is being closed by a button, with this piece of code:

```
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close()
```

like

```
<button type="submit" onclick="parent.jQuery.colorbox.close()" ....
```

can I somehow time this event? So it will close after 2sec. ex?

I'am using the ColorBox lib.

Comment: after 2 sec of clicking close button ..?

Comment: Yes, somehow. It is because it's an Iframe that sends a submit, and after that I want it to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="setTimeout(parent.jQuery.colorbox.close,2000)" ...
```

setTimeout will delay the execution of anything by a specified number of milliseconds, in this case 2000.

Comment: Hi robert and thanks, but it didn't quite work as expected. It still just closes instantly, I've tried to set the timer for 10sec+ but that was not the problem apparently.

Comment: This worked fine, it was because I'm "reloading" the page when the form is submitted, so the function is not started. I must think of another way to do this.